# Sending data with post ajax to asp.net MVC controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am tried sent a data from view with ajax (POST) to controller in JSON format. From console.log, data is correct but data in controller missing...

Here is controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SavePermission(TestData testData)
{
    return Json("DONE");
}
```

Here is model:

```
namespace INTRANETv4.Models
{
    public class TestData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public bool read { get; set; }
        public bool write { get; set; }
        public bool delete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is javascript function from View:

```
function Save() { 
        var rows = document.getElementById("userTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var output = [];
        for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            output.push({
                id: rows[i].id,
                read: rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked,
                write: rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked,
                delete: rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked
            });
        }
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(output);
        console.log(myJSON);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: myJSON,
            url: "/Files/SavePermission",
            dataType: "json"
        });
}
```

Here is console.log of myJSON:

[image]

And here is content of testData from controller while debugging:

[image]

When i used string testData, because i worried about to convert, string was null. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You are posting an array, therefore the parameter in the POST method must be `List<TestData> testData`

Comment: I changed TestData to List<TestData> but Count = 0. Same problem...

Answer (score 0):

try
you model change to     `List<TestData> testData`

and data change to JSON.stringify({ testData: output }),

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:  JSON.stringify({ testData: output }),
            url: "/Files/SavePermission",
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

Comment: You tried it? Because for me not working. The list in controller have Count = 0...

Comment: sorry i forget json.stringify     data: JSON.stringify({ testData: output }),  I tried  is working

Comment: No. I dont know why. But i find another way how to do that. I did this: `data: { testData: JSON.stringify(output) }` and remove `contentType: "application/json"` and change `public ActionResult SavePermission(string testData)`. Only this working for me. I have no idea why i cant set outgoing data and map it on class model. And sory for take usefull answer and question. That was not me...